# How can I sniff the packets from IP(s) of other devices connected to the same local wireless network?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, sniffing, network-security

I am able to capture only the packets routed through my NIC, but I want to sniff all the packets from other PC(s) connected to the same local wireless network. I am using Wireshark, but it cannot sniff the packets from the remote IP(s) connected to the same local network (created by a wireless router).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much detail about your capture setup - in particular what OS your capture PC is running or what hardware you have.  The best advice I can give you to start with is to visit the Wireshark [WLAN (IEEE 802.11) capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) wiki page and carefully read its contents, particularly those sections that best relate to your system.  At the very least, you will need to be able to place your wireless NIC into monitor mode, and the method by which you do that is OS dependent, so do visit that wiki page for more details.

If you happen to be running Windows and you are unable to place your NIC into monitor mode using Wireshark or you don't have an adaptor (such as an Airpcap adaptor) capable of capturing the traffic, or npcap doesn't work for you, then you might want to try other tools besides Wireshark, such as Microsoft's [*Network Monitor*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or their newer [*Message Analyzer*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) capture tools.

Lastly, if nothing else works, then you might want to visit the Wireshark [*Tools*](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) wiki page to try to find other potential tools that might work for you in your particular capture environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cain and Abel sniffing tool. It is very easy one. You can sniff packets by Cain and Abel and log them using WireShark.

You can download it from https://web.archive.org/web/20190603235413/http://www.oxid.it/cain.html

Comment: the site leads to an unsecured and risky page flagged by both chrome and opera.

Comment: @HimanshuSourav What do you mean by that?  I see no warnings, and I'm redirected to the HTTPS site (which I've now updated the link to).  If you're seeing something else, you may have an issue on your end.

Comment: @RyanM
link provided i.e. https://sectools.org/tool/cain/ cannot be used to download the suggested tools.

did you actually click the link provided on the website?

The link to actual site from where one can download the tools is Dead/Hijacked and now used for phishing/ads and rightly blocked by chrome.

There are no functional content links on the site anymore.

Comment: @HimanshuSourav thanks; I've updated the link to point to an archived version of the page.